# Hypergeometric function/series motivation and vs. Taylor expansion

Tags: hypergeometric-function

The real and complex hypergeometric series $F(a,b;c;z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_{(n)} b_{(n)}}{c_{(n)}n!}z^n$ is absolutely convergent when the real part of $a+b-c-1$ is less than $-1$. It has several applications in differential equation and integral perhaps because it’s related to exponential, log and power functions, and its derivative has a similar form.

My questions are:

1. What’s the historical motivation of this series? Several uses of the series appear here: [Motivating Hypergeometric Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/851471/577710), but I’m wondering when the series began to come about and be investigated.
2. Since the series looks like a Taylor expansion, if a function $f(z)=F(a,b;c;z)$ (or it has similar expressions), then do we have $f^{(n)}(0) =\frac{a_{(n)} b_{(n)}}{c_{(n)}}$ (or similar conclusions)?

Comment: Yes to your second question. As for the first, Euler and Gauss started investigating this class of functions. It is now a very useful tool, because advanced software (like Mathematica) can evaluate these functions for arbitrary parameters